# Using Brute Force to generate all possible combination of binary numbers as array?

Tags: java, arrays, brute-force

I want to use the Brute Force algorithm to generate all possible combinations of {0,1} as arrays.
For example, I want to generate 2^3 different combinations of binary numbers array, should be

```
{{0,0,0},
{1,0,0},
{0,1,0},
{0,0,1},
{1,1,0},
{0,1,1},
{1,0,1},
{1,1,1}}
```

how do you generate these arrays using brute force in java? Please let me know if my question is unclear, thank you!!

Comment: A loop from one to seven would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example of your code. You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

In regards to your question, using three loops can be a solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var combinations = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                    combinations.add(new int[] {i, j, k});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can print them like this:

```
for (var c : combinations) 
{
    System.out.printf("{%d,%d,%d}%n", c[0], c[1], c[2]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about directly giving an answer to someone who seemingly has not made any attempt before asking their question...

Comment: @Musilix I've edited the question to suggest the OP to provide a minimal reproducible code sample.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for not providing enough information regarding my question. I will do better next time by reading through the rules of how to ask good questions in StackOverflow. However, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BruteForceBinary {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many rows do you want? ");
        int rows = scanner.nextInt(); 
        int finalNumber = (int) (Math.pow(2, rows)-1); 
        for (int i = 0; i <=finalNumber; i++ )
        {
            int[] binaryArray = numberToBinaryArray(i,rows);
            
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(binaryArray));
        }
    }

    private static int[] numberToBinaryArray(int i, int rows ) {
        String binaryString = padLeftZeros(Integer.toBinaryString(i), rows);
        int[] numbers = new int[binaryString.length()];
        for (int j = 0; j < binaryString.length(); j++ ) {
            numbers[j] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(binaryString.charAt(j)));
        }
        return numbers;
    }
    
    private static String padLeftZeros(String inputString, int length) {
        if (inputString.length() >= length) {
            return inputString;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (sb.length() < length - inputString.length()) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        sb.append(inputString);
     
        return sb.toString();
    }


}
```